# Linq to Entity Group By error can't translate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I try to do this query:

```
var query = from cont in _gpiContext.Contacto
                        join per in _gpiContext.Persona on cont.IdPersona equals per.IdPersona
                        where cont.IdCliente == idCliente
                        && cont.IdTipoContacto == tipoContacto.IdTipoContacto
                        group new { cont, per } by new { cont.IdCliente, cont.IdContacto, cont.IdPersona } into g
                        select new Representante
                        {
                            IdContacto = g.Key.IdContacto,
                            IdCliente = g.Key.IdCliente,
                            IdPersona = g.Key.IdPersona,
                            Nombre = g.First().per.Nombre
                        };
return await query.ToListAsync();
```

I have tried everything, but cant figure out what is wrong, I have very similar querys and they do work flawlessly. I **don't** want to do client evaluation.

But I Get the Following Error:

> "The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new {
> IdCliente = (Nullable)c.ID_CLIENTE,
> IdContacto = c.ID_CONTACTO,
> IdPersona = (Nullable)c.ID_PERSONA  },  ElementSelector:new {
> con = EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Contacto
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: con
> IsNullable: False
> ,
> per = EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: Persona
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: per
> IsNullable: True  }
> .Select(s => s.per.Nombre)
> .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly
> by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList',
> or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038
> for more information."

My Entityes:
Contacto

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

#nullable disable

namespace GpiWebApp.Data.Gpi
{
    [Table("CONTACTO")]
    public partial class Contacto
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ID_CONTACTO", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
        public decimal IdContacto { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_CLIENTE", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
        public decimal? IdCliente { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_TIPO_CONTACTO", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
        public decimal? IdTipoContacto { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_PERSONA", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
        public decimal? IdPersona { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(IdCliente))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Cliente.Contacto))]
        public virtual Cliente IdClienteNavigation { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(IdPersona))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Persona.Contacto))]
        public virtual Persona IdPersonaNavigation { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(IdTipoContacto))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(TipoContacto.Contacto))]
        public virtual TipoContacto IdTipoContactoNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Persona

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated by EF Core Power Tools. </auto-generated>
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
    #nullable disable
    
    namespace GpiWebApp.Data.Gpi
    {
        [Table("PERSONA")]
        public partial class Persona
        {
            public Persona()
            {
                Cliente = new HashSet<Cliente>();
                Contacto = new HashSet<Contacto>();
                DireccionPersona = new HashSet<DireccionPersona>();
                EmailPersona = new HashSet<EmailPersona>();
                TelefonoPersona = new HashSet<TelefonoPersona>();
            }
    
            [Key]
            [Column("ID_PERSONA", TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
            public decimal IdPersona { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Column("TIPO_ENTIDAD")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string TipoEntidad { get; set; }
            [Column("NOMBRE")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Nombre { get; set; }
            [Column("PATERNO")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Paterno { get; set; }
            [Column("MATERNO")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Materno { get; set; }
            [Column("SEXO")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string Sexo { get; set; }
            [Column("FECHA_NACIMIENTO", TypeName = "datetime")]
            public DateTime? FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Column("IDENTIFICADOR")]
            [StringLength(12)]
            public string Identificador { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [Column("TIPO_IDENTIFICADOR")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string TipoIdentificador { get; set; }
            [Column("COD_PAIS")]
            [StringLength(3)]
            public string CodPais { get; set; }
            [Column("ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", TypeName = "numeric(3, 0)")]
            public decimal? IdEstadoCivil { get; set; }
            [Column("PROFESION")]
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string Profesion { get; set; }
            [Column("TELEFONO")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Telefono { get; set; }
            [Column("CELULAR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Celular { get; set; }
            [Column("EMAIL")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Email { get; set; }
            [Column("EMPLEADOR")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Empleador { get; set; }
            [Column("CARGO")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Cargo { get; set; }
            [Column("FLG_MAYOR_EDAD")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string FlgMayorEdad { get; set; }
            [Column("ID_TIPO_ESTADO", TypeName = "numeric(4, 0)")]
            public decimal? IdTipoEstado { get; set; }
            [Column("COD_ESTADO")]
            [StringLength(3)]
            public string CodEstado { get; set; }
            [Column("GIRO")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Giro { get; set; }
            [Column("ID_TIPO_SOCIEDAD", TypeName = "numeric(3, 0)")]
            public decimal? IdTipoSociedad { get; set; }
            [Column("DSC_DOCUMENTO")]
            [StringLength(20)]
            public string DscDocumento { get; set; }
            [Column("OBSERVACIONES")]
            [StringLength(150)]
            public string Observaciones { get; set; }
            [Column("COPIA_ESCRITURA")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string CopiaEscritura { get; set; }
            [Column("FECHA_FORMACION", TypeName = "datetime")]
            public DateTime? FechaFormacion { get; set; }
            [Column("LUGAR")]
            [StringLength(80)]
            public string Lugar { get; set; }
            [Column("NOTARIA")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Notaria { get; set; }
            [Column("REGISTRO")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Registro { get; set; }
            [Column("NUMERO")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Numero { get; set; }
            [Column("ANO")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Ano { get; set; }
            [Column("ANTECEDENTES")]
            [StringLength(1)]
            public string Antecedentes { get; set; }
            [Column("SITIOWEB")]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Sitioweb { get; set; }
    
            [ForeignKey(nameof(CodPais))]
            [InverseProperty(nameof(Pais.Persona))]
            public virtual Pais CodPaisNavigation { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey(nameof(IdEstadoCivil))]
            [InverseProperty(nameof(EstadoCivil.Persona))]
            public virtual EstadoCivil IdEstadoCivilNavigation { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey(nameof(IdTipoSociedad))]
            [InverseProperty(nameof(TipoSociedad.Persona))]
            public virtual TipoSociedad IdTipoSociedadNavigation { get; set; }
            [InverseProperty("IdPersonaNavigation")]
            public virtual ICollection<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
            [InverseProperty("IdPersonaNavigation")]
            public virtual ICollection<Contacto> Contacto { get; set; }
            [InverseProperty("IdPersonaNavigation")]
            public virtual ICollection<DireccionPersona> DireccionPersona { get; set; }
            [InverseProperty("IdPersonaNavigation")]
            public virtual ICollection<EmailPersona> EmailPersona { get; set; }
            [InverseProperty("IdPersonaNavigation")]
            public virtual ICollection<TelefonoPersona> TelefonoPersona { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I am wondering where is it from tipoContacto.IdTipoContacto?

Answer (score 1):

why don't try this

```
....
group new { cont, per } by new { cont.IdCliente, cont.IdContacto, cont.IdPersona, per.Nombre } into g
  select new Representante
    {
     IdContacto = g.Key.IdContacto,
       IdCliente = g.Key.IdCliente,
       IdPersona = g.Key.IdPersona,
       Nombre = g.Key.Nombre
      };
```

Comment: Why don't they try? Well, that's a totally different grouping. OP doesn't want to group by `Nombre`. Again an impulsive answer in which you prematurely assume that OP will change their requirements just like that. Of course the only correct answer here is that EF doesn't support it and that they have to find a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

[Serge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69125741/5623232) should work for this particular case, but I thought I'd add some context before you try to do more complex things with grouping in LINQ.

Have a look at the [Complex query operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby) section on the EFCore documentation. Especially interesting is the part where they said:

> Since no database structure can represent an `IGrouping`, GroupBy operators have no translation in most cases.

This makes sense, because if you think in SQL terms, there's very few aggregations you can do on a GROUP BY, e.g. SUM, COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX; but there is no FIRST or LAST (unless you get into partitioning and ranking which is like grouping, but not really).

So, long story short, your query is actually *valid LINQ*. If you try and apply it to a `List<>` it would work. But it can never be translated to server-side SQL.